# What is the blank part in Chrome performance (timeline) tool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

My page has some performance issues and I use Chrome dev tool to find the problem of the page.

[image]

This is a screenshot of performance result and have the following questions :
1. Does this mean that the browser spent 38.1ms rendering this frame?
2. According to my knowledge, functions should be executed sequentially and fill all the blank areas in a frame, but Chrome tells me that there are two blank areas and nothing is executed during this time. Why? What exactly did the browser perform during these two blank periods?

Comment: These gaps are where the browser isn't running any JavaScript. Could be doing anything else though, rendering, waiting for user input or waiting for resource to load, as these generally run asynchronously.